# Does downvoting count against progress towards the "Earned at least 200 reputation" badges?

Tags: support, reputation, downvotes

Yesterday I earned exactly 200 reputation. However I also down voted an answer. This means in total my reputation gain for yesterday was +199:

[image: Reputation Gain]

Despite actually earning 200 reputation, my [/reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) page's *earned at least 200 reputation* count hasn't gone up.

Does downvoting count against progress towards the *earned at least 200 reputation* badges? If so, why does it?

I did *earn* 200 reputation, after all.

Comment: A comment to go alongside the -1 vote here would have been nice as I really don't know what that's supposed to imply by itself...

Comment: See here, including comments: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181103/158667 - the calculation doesn't take downvotes into account, but the `/reputation` link isn't accurate.

Comment: @Mat I see, thanks for finding that!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As pointed out by [Mat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/635608/mat) in [his comment on my question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280878/does-downvoting-count-against-progress-towards-the-earned-at-least-200-reputati#comment132626_280878): [This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181103/211113) on Stack Exchange's Meta explains that down votes both given and received do not count towards the *earned at least 200 reputation* requirement:

> ...whether you cast or receive them [down votes], they will no longer deduct from your daily total towards Mortarboard, Epic, and Legendary.
> *–  [Jarrod Dixon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/3/jarrod-dixon) May 21 '13*

Presumably this is still the case.